# Passing data between view controllers inside UITabBarController without segues

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have been looking for answer to this question for a long time. I can use `prepareforSegue` if I am using segues. As we know, `UITabBar` doesn't have segues like navigation controller. In one of my view controllers, I am fetching data from firebase, and I have observer set up to listen for any changes. I want to use data fetched from firebase in this controller to access in another view controller. For example, I want to access this `entryIDs` in another view controller, and also listen to any changes made to this array, so I can reload data in my collectionView. To sum it up, how do I access array from one view controller to another inside UITabBarController, and also listen to any changes made to it?

```
var entries = [String: DiaryEntry]()
var entryIDs =  [String]()

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.register(DiaryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "homeCell")
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    if let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
        FirebaseService.service.getUserEntriesRef(uid: userID).observe(.value, with: { [weak weakSelf = self] (snapshot) in
            weakSelf?.entries = [String: DiaryEntry]()
            weakSelf?.entryIDs = [String]()
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let entry = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                weakSelf?.entryIDs.append(entry.key)
                weakSelf?.entries[entry.key] = DiaryEntry(snapshot: entry)
            }
            weakSelf?.entryIDs.reverse()
            weakSelf?.collectionView?.reloadData()
        })
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: best way to get an eye on updates and passing data is notification. Use NSNotification. Or if data is more and in object form then go for singleton class.

Comment: or a singleton shared between all of your view controllers

Comment: You can use `NsNotification` or `Singleton` or you can implement `TabBarController Delegate` method which gives you the instance of the controller and you can set property for that controller. It depends on requirement.

Comment: @KamalSharma Can you track updates through singleton class? Is there any good resource you can point me to for creating singleton classes?

Answer (score 0):

On sending info

```
let infoDict = ["info" : self.info]

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "passInfo"), object: nil, userInfo : infoDict as! [String : AnyObject])
```

on receiving info

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.doSomething), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "passInfo"), object: nil)


func doSomething(_ notification : Notification) {

   let info = notification.userInfo!["info"] as! Int
   //Do something
}
```